# Muddy Fox Pathfinder 90s MTB

Tags: mountain-bike

Not such a specific issue but a general question, I am interested in repairing a bike and for £10 there is a Muddyfox Pathfinder from the 90s, is this worth the £10, does it have any value or should I leave it?
Thanks
Charlie

Comment: We do not do item valuations here. You can ask about the properties or advantages of something, but do not ask whether it is worth 10 quid. You must ask yourself, is this bike worth the tenner *for me*? Different people will have different answers to that and one must inspect such a bike first.

Comment: If the frame is in good condition and you are prepared to put time and money into other parts of the bike, it's hard to see how it's a bad deal.-they were good quality bikes.

Answer (score 2):

We can't give valuations - that's considered off-topic because they're highly region-specific, and go out of date fast.

The bike you're looking at is available here-and-now, and the seller is asking a token sum.  In these days of C19 and shaky supply lines, any bike is better than no bike.

**If you need a bicycle, and this one fits your body, you find it comfortable, and the bike is mechanically sound then grab it.**

---

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/token%20payment says

> Definition of token payment
> : a very small payment made upon a debt and intended by the payer merely to acknowledge the existence of the obligation

If an item is given freely with no cost, then the receiver may not value it sufficiently.  By asking a **nominal charge** then the receiver is more likely to value the item, whatever it is.

I used to volunteer for a bike fixup, and there were a group of local kids.  Every 3 months they would come and ask for a replacement bike because they'd dropped their previous, or put it down and forgotten it, or left it outside and it was pinched.  A lack of cost and easy access to replacements meant they did not appreciate what they had.  
Problem was solved by asking them for the old bike back so it could be handed onto the next user.

So 10 UKP is there to make the buyer value the item, but seller also feels they've got something out of the trade.  The actual cost is small (often about the cost of one person's lunch, or sometimes as little as $1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is worthwhile. See it this way: for 10 pounds/eur/usd you will commit yourself to rebuild a bicycle starting from a decent steel frame, plus you will have a deep understanding of the value of bicycle parts.

Years ago I bought a steel frame (Trek 750) for 10Euro (with fork), for 10Euro I bought a fitting rear wheel with 9 gears ... then I brought it to a friendly bike shop to install the handlebar, gears, bottom bracket, cranks, front wheel. I admit I am a special sort of tinkerer: the lazy tinkerer.

They charged me around 100Euro (cheap, reliable, and mostly used parts). I was very happy with their service ([link to said bikeshop](https://www.velomondo.de/)).

Then I bought a cheap seatpost, saddle, brakes et voilà, for roughly 150Euro I had a great bike (orders of magnitude better than department store bikes costing 199Euro or similar prices).
I was very happy.

One year later, I spent 120Euro for a new saddle for that bicycle.

--- FIN ---